# Rails relationships with foreign key between?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I have two entities in my Rails app for which I'm trying to establish a relationship - checks and months. Instances of Month will have a start_date and an end_date - these dates do not exactly align to the calendar month.  Instances of Check will have a deposit_date.  I want to somehow describe a relationship where months have many checks, where the deposit date is between the start and end date of the month. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was to remove the has_many :checks from the Month class, and defined my own method:

```
class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other associations and validations omitted

  def checks
    Check.where(deposit_date: self.start_date..self.end_date)
  end
end
```

I don't know if this would be considered a hack, but it gave me what I needed.  I'm open to seeing a more 'Rails way' to do this, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.  You can customize your `relation` reference.

```
class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checks, ->(month) { where deposited_at: (month.start_at)..(month.end_at) }, class_name: 'Check'
end
```

You don't actually need to specify the `class_name`, unless you change your relation name. For example, if you had `current_checks` instead of naming it simply `checks`.

Comment: Was that answer helpful?

Comment: actually, i subsequently found that though this approach did not error out on me, did not give me the expected results.  the problem was that it was still expecting a primary key/foreign key relationship between checks and months, and appended the lambda to the end of the statement.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I would have assumed you had that in place, as that's standard rails conventions.