# 4-way relationship in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set up some relationships in my Rails 4 application, but I"m having some trouble.  I have four classes as follows:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checks
  belongs_to :tier
  has_many :months
end

class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :group, class_name: "Month"
end

class Tier < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :months
end

class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  belongs_to :tier
  has_many :checks, ->(month) { where deposit_date: month.start_date..month.end_date }

  validates_uniqueness_of :group, scope: :tier_id
end
```

**Edit**: To clarify, there are three 'tiers' that have a distinct month structure, e.g. Tier 1's 'January' will start on the first, Tier 2 will start on the third, and so on.  It's designed so that there are only three tiers (i.e. three different month structures), and a Client will only have one tier, but many months through this tier.  There is also a restriction on the month table to ensure there is no more than 1 entry per month for the same tier.  Essentially it's a habtm relationship between months and clients, but it's the tier that the client is in that determines which 'group' it gets back.

The tables are setup in such a way so that clients and months both have a tier_id foreign key, a check has a client_id foreign key and a deposit date, a month has a tier_id and a start and end date.  The tiers table is more or less a placeholder for the name of the tier (Tier 1, Tier 2), and was intended to unite a client with their months. I want to be able to describe @client.months, where it will find all the months in the table that match the tier of the client.  And further I want to do something like @month.checks, which will find all the checks posted for a particular client in a particular month.  But I'm running into all kinds of trouble.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to make my current schema work, if I need to make alterations, or if I need to rethink the whole thing from the ground up!  And, more importantly, how to get there....

**Edit**:

An example of what I'm trying to get back from the database would take the following form in SQL:

```
SELECT ch.*
FROM clients cl
JOIN tiers t ON cl.tier_id = t.id
JOIN months m ON m.tier_id = t.id
JOIN checks ch ON ch.client_id = clients.id
WHERE clients.id = ? AND m.group = ?
```

or, more simply:

```
SELECT ch.*
FROM clients cl
JOIN months m ON m.tier_id = cl.tier_id
JOIN checks ch ON ch.client_id = clients.id
WHERE clients.id = ? AND m.group = ?
```

Comment: belongs_to should always be singular... `belongs_to :tier`

Comment: Can you explain what a tier actually is?

Comment: @depa I have just updated my question to help explain what a tier is and how it relates to the other models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I did not realize it at first, I have inadvertently answered my own question by solving a smaller issue here:  [Rails relationships with foreign key between?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898693/rails-relationships-with-foreign-key-between)

As I stated in my answer there, though this gives me what I wanted, it doesn't feel like the 'Rails Way', so I'm open to suggestions on how to improve the solution.

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation it explains that Tier is the intermediate model which joins Client and Month.

So you can have the reference of clients and months table on tiers, that means tiers table should have client_id and month_id.

Remove tire_id from clients table if you have before and similarly remove tier_id from months table also.

And have the model association with **has_many :through** relationship as below so you can access **client.months** and **month.clients**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checks
  has_many :tiers
  has_many :months, through: :tiers
end

class Tier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :month
end

class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tiers
  has_many :clients, through: :tiers
  has_many :checks, -> { where deposit_date: start_date..end_date }
end

class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :group, class_name: "Month"
end
```

Note:
* Add client_id and month_id to tiers table
* Remove tier_id from months table
* Remove tier_id from clients table

Comment: I can understand this approach, however it would make the tiers table grow in size and redundancy with each client and month added, whereas in my mind it should only have 3 rows.  I've considered bypassing the tiers table altogether and establishing a habtm relationship between months and clients with a new client_months table - would that not make more sense?

Comment: If you have any additional fields required apart from just mapping two tables then you can go with has_many through or you can simply use HABTM